# Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties at object declaration and initialization level

Tags: java, jackson

I have a Java class. I obtain a new object of the class. But I don't want to obtain all the instance variables returned by the object class getters, and I also do not want to annotate @JsonIgnoreProperties at the entity level. Can I be able to set up the ignorals at the class object's initialization level.

e.g.

Scenario:

```
class A {
    String as;

    public String getAs() {
        return this.as;
    }
}


class B {
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("as")
    A a = new A();
}
```

Comment: Consider using a [filter](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureJsonFilter).

Comment: Wow. Thanks. You should have posted as the answer to the question for future reference by other devs.